# How to fix "return 0 / exit(0) not working properly inside for loop"?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, return, exit

I was making a scientific calculator. And thought of looping the statements until the user asks to stop by using 0 as one of the options. But even after entering 0. It asks one last time this statement:
`printf("Enter two numbers (For only one no. required you can just enter other number anything)\n");`

I have tried using `goto, exit(0)` and `return` 0 statements. Even `while(1)` and `for(;;)` loop also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    float b,c;
    float d=3.14159/180;
    while(1)
    {
    printf("\nScientific Calculator :\n");
    printf("Enter option:\n 0- Exit, 1-Add, 2-Sub, 3-Multiply, 4-Divide,\n 5-sin(x), 6-cos(x), 7-tan(x), 8-sinh(x), 9-cosh(x), 10-tanh(x),\n11-log10(x),12-exponent,13-power of x w.r.t y \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter two numbers (For only one no. required you can just enter other number anything)\n"); //Here is where it starts even after return 0
    scanf("%f%f",&b,&c); //Here after inputting value it ends.
    switch(a)
    {
        case 0:return 0; //Here is the return 0;
        case 1:printf("%d",(int)(b+c)); break;
        case 2:printf("%d",(int)(b-c)); break;
        case 3:printf("%d",(int)(b*c)); break;
        case 4:printf("%f",b/c); break;
        case 5:printf("%f",sin(b*d)); break;
        case 6:printf("%f",cos(b*d)); break;
        case 7:printf("%f",tan(b*d)); break;
        case 8:printf("%f",sinh(b*d)); break;
        case 9:printf("%f",cosh(b*d)); break;
        case 10:printf("%f",cosh(b*d)); break;
        case 11:printf("%f",tanh(b*d)); break;
        case 12:printf("%f",log10(b)); break;
        case 13:printf("%f",exp(b)); break;
        case 14:printf("%f",pow(b,c)); break;
        default:printf("Enter correct option\n");
    }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I wanted it to just exit and come out of the program but it is asking input `printf("Enter two numbers ---\n");` and after inputting values it exits.

Comment: some basic checks on scanf woud be nice

Comment: you check the case 0 too late, see my answer

Comment: IMHO, this is more the `printf("Enter two number` which is done too early, you should know what you are going to do with them before asking for parameters.

Comment: @OznOg you are right for the cases 12 and 13

Comment: it is also useless to read numbers if the choice is invalid, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

> But even after entering 0. It asks one last time this statement: `printf("Enter two numbers (For only one no. required you can just enter other number anything)\n");`

you need to check the case '0' immediately, so

> ```
>  printf("Enter option:\n 0- Exit, 1-Add, 2-Sub, 3-Multiply, 4-Divide,\n 5-sin(x), 6-cos(x), 7-tan(x), 8-sinh(x), 9-cosh(x), 10-tanh(x),\n11-log10(x),12-exponent,13-power of x w.r.t y \n");
>  scanf("%d",&a);
>  printf("Enter two numbers (For only one no. required you can just enter other number anything)\n"); //Here is where it starts even after return 0
>  scanf("%f%f",&b,&c); //Here after inputting value it ends.
>  switch(a)
>     case 0:return 0; //Here is the return 0;
>     case 1:printf("%d",(int)(b+c)); break;
>     ...
> ```

must be

```
printf("Enter option:\n 0- Exit, 1-Add, 2-Sub, 3-Multiply, 4-Divide,\n 5-sin(x), 6-cos(x), 7-tan(x), 8-sinh(x), 9-cosh(x), 10-tanh(x),\n11-log10(x),12-exponent,13-power of x w.r.t y \n");
scanf("%d",&a);
if (a == 0)
  return 0;

printf("Enter two numbers (For only one no. required you can just enter other number anything)\n"); //Here is where it starts even after return 0
scanf("%f%f",&b,&c); //Here after inputting value it ends.
switch(a)
   case 1:printf("%d",(int)(b+c)); break;
   ...
```

Note it can also be a good idea to check a valid *int* was enter, so to check if `scanf("%d",&a)` returns 1, and the same for `scanf("%f%f",&b,&c)` so checking it returns 2 ...

As said in a remark by @OznOg for the cases 12 and 13 you need to read only one number, not two. Note also it is useless to ask for number if the code is invalid, so :

```
  if (scanf("%d",&a) != 1)
    return -1;

  if (a == 0)
    return 0;

  if ((a < 0) || (a > 14))
    printf("Enter correct option\n");
  else if ((a == 12) || (a == 13)) {
    printf("Enter one number\n");
    if (scanf("%f",&b) != 1)
      return -1;
    if (a == 12)
      printf("%f",log10(b)); 
    else
      printf("%f",exp(b)); break;
  }
  else {
    printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    if (scanf("%f%f",&b,&c) != 2)
      return -1;
    switch(a)
    {
    case 1:printf("%d",(int)(b+c)); break;
    case 2:printf("%d",(int)(b-c)); break;
    case 3:printf("%d",(int)(b*c)); break;
    case 4:printf("%f",b/c); break;
    case 5:printf("%f",sin(b*d)); break;
    case 6:printf("%f",cos(b*d)); break;
    case 7:printf("%f",tan(b*d)); break;
    case 8:printf("%f",sinh(b*d)); break;
    case 9:printf("%f",cosh(b*d)); break;
    case 10:printf("%f",cosh(b*d)); break;
    case 11:printf("%f",tanh(b*d)); break;
    case 14:printf("%f",pow(b,c)); break;
    }
  }
```